# writing embedded loops in seaborn to make histograms in separate windows and setting plot titles to column names

Tags: pandas, for-loop, seaborn, nested-loops

I'm trying to make histograms for PM2.5/PM10 ratios for 24 hour average data for around 50 sites and want the histograms to be in separate windows. I have a code that works, but it automatically sets the x-axis label as the site name. I figured out how to change the x labels but am having trouble writing a loop that changes the title name for each figure. Here's the part of the code that works:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i,col in enumerate(pmf.columns):
    plt.figure(i)
    sns.histplot(pmf[col], binwidth=0.05, color='green')
    plt.xlim(0,1)
    plt.xlabel('PM$_{2.5}$/PM$_{10}$', fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=15)
```

Here is some sample data to work with: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1heF1W1x0qS_5SjjPg23j5alt2WiY3HsM/view?usp=sharing

I have trouble with embedding another loop that automatically changes the title based on a list of titles:

```
titles = ['1201 West Hwy 98', 'Betty Jo Mcneece Receiving Home',
       'Booker T. Washington Elementary', 'CCV', 'Calexico, 604 Kubler Rd',
       'Calexico, Alvarez', 'Calexico, Encinas Ave and Ethel St',
       'Calexico, Ethel', 'Calexico, Housing Authority',
       'Calexico, Housing Authority West', 'Calexico, Residence',
       'Dogwood Rd & HWY 98', 'El Centro West', 'El Centro, Wilson',
       'Frank Wright', "Gio's Mobile Home Estates", 'Heber',
       'Holtville, 1015 Miller Rd', 'Holtville, High School',
       'Holtville, South', 'Imperial County APCD', 'Kennedy', 'Meadows',
       'Ocotillo', 'Portico Blvd', 'Seeley', 'TL Waggoner',
       'Wozencraft Street & Acuña Ave']
```

I thought maybe I could add an additional variable to the first loop as so `#for col, t in zip(enumerate(pmf.columns), titles):`, but got an error message that said `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2).`

I tried this:

```
for i,col in enumerate(pmf.columns):
    plt.figure(i)
    sns.histplot(pmf[col], binwidth=0.05, color='green')
    plt.xlim(0,1)
    plt.xlabel('PM$_{2.5}$/PM$_{10}$', fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=15)
    for t in titles:
        plt.title(t, fontsize=20)
```

but this makes the title of all of the figures the last site name in the title list provided (Wozencraft...).
I also tried

```
for t in titles:
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.title(t, fontsize=20)
    for col in enumerate(pmf.columns):    
        fig.sns.histplot(pmf[col], binwidth=0.05, color='green')
        plt.xlim(0,1)
        plt.xlabel('PM$_{2.5}$/PM$_{10}$', fontsize=15)
        plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=15)
```

but it created blank figures with a title and an error message that said `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'sns'`

If someone could help me, I will appreciate it.

Comment: `ax = plt.subplot()`, `ax.set_title(t, fontsize=20)`, and `sns.histplot(pmf[col], binwidth=0.05, color='green', ax=ax)`

Comment: `titles` is the same thing as `pmf.columns[1:]` i.e. it just drops `date` column. Also, it doesn't make sense to get a histplot of `date` column as it doesn't contain numerical values. What I understand is you want to plot column histplots except `date`, right?

Comment: @NuriTaş oh yeah I'm not plotting the dates - in my code the date is the index.

Comment: @NuriTaş your code was almost correct. I tried ```plt.title(pmf.columns[1:])``` and it did not work, gave ```ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()``` so I tried ```plt.title(pmf.columns[i]) and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I added this line of code to the loop and it worked:

```
plt.title(pmf.columns[i])
```